# Mouse cursor stuck in top left of screen but can still move and interact with invisible mouse

Tags: mouse, 16.10

I just installed Ubuntu 16.10 on my desktop and have a USB deathadder. The problem is I can't see where the cursor actually is because it appears only in the top left of my screen. The mouse still moves but the cursor graphic doesn't follow

Comment: I am suffering from this same issue. If it is any help, this happened right after I installed a new GTX 1070 GPU. This issue happens in the installer or when ubuntu is booted from live-USB for 16.10.

Comment: @ThomasAntony yeah I have a GTX 1070 and I can't get ANY distro of ubuntu to properly work with it. It is super frustrating!

Comment: I could get it to move if I added nomodeset in the boot options. Of course, this makes the graphics reset to low-res. But I could at least get through the installer. I guess this means there is some specific driver that is causing this issue? I will let you know if this persists after the installation is done. 

This could be specific to 16.10. I installed Linux Mint which I assume is based on the LTS version and the mouse worked fine.

Comment: Just found this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/838692/ubuntu-16-10-mouse-cursor-stays-in-upper-left-corner

Could fix our issues.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by installing the nvidia-370 drivers. Try the following steps:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> at the login screen. This will drop you down into a console where you can login to your user account.
2. Run `sudo service lightdm stop`
3. Use the following commands to download and install nvidia-370. Make sure you are connected to the internet: 

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-370 nvidia-settings`
4. Disable the `nouveau` driver. This step may be unnecessary but I did it anyway. Edit the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and add `blacklist nouveau` at the bottom. Save and Exit.
5. Run the command `sudo update-initramfs -u`
6. Restart with `sudo reboot`

Comment: I will try this and let you know if this works for me! Would be fantastic :D

Answer (score 1):

Seems like sometimes the cursor will freeze especially on touch-enabled devices.

1. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> (use <kbd>Fn</kbd> if needed in your keyboard to activate the function keys).
2. Type letter `r` on the dialogue box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This will restart the Graphical User Interface (GUI) service and your cursor will be back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

try rebooting.
That happened to me too.
I went trough this problem on xubuntu. I tried rebooting and the curser reappeared.
Thats all I know.
I hope this helps!

Comment: I've tried rebooting a lot. The cursor is there, just the graphic is stuck in the top left corner. I can still use the mouse as if it works I just can't see where it is!