# Ubuntu 16.10 Mouse cursor stays in upper left corner

Tags: nvidia, login, mouse, lightdm, gdm

After crashing my Ubuntu 16.04 with installing nvidia drivers I installed Ubuntu 16.10

However my cursor is not moving anymore. It stays in the upper left corner. It is moving invisible (detected through hovering over icons)
I installed Ubuntu without moving mouse...

I tried following without success

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

Nothing changed.

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Neither there.
I installed gdm instead but then i was not even able to get to the login gui or even tty. So went back to lightdm.

Reenabling the mousedriver did nothing.

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

Nothing changed.

After installing nvidia driver with

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

I was able to move my mouse again, however I was stuck in the well known Ubuntu login loop. The common solution with .Xauthority and other solutions did not work. Had these problems with Ubuntu 10.04. Even my resolution was worse after that.
After removing the nvidia-driver I was able to login again, but no moving cursor.

Is this a graphics problem? I have a Nvidia GTX 1070 Ti

Any solutions?
Thank you.

Comment: GTX1070 works with 367 or 370 only. Neither are provided by *nvidia-current*.

Comment: That did it. After installing nvidia-367 everything works fine. Thank you!

Comment: I'm having the same problem, only installing nvidia-367 didn't do it. Any ideas? It's a fresh Ubuntu 16.10 install.

Comment: Holy crap, it worked! Signed up for this site just to say that I owe CelticWarrior my life

Comment: This seems to be the official bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1646574 Not sure how long it takes for the fix to make it to the official Ubuntu installer though...

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt to install the driver caused a login loop. The reason in my case is I didn't disable secure boot after the installation. So, I uninstalled the driver, reinstalled it, rebooted the computer and disabled secure boot.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-367
```

remember to reboot and there will be a count down page for you to disable secure boot.