# Cursor getting stuck in launcher

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics

It's a weird issue. The cursor gets stuck in place but still moves so that if I click I click on what I aimed to but the cursor is not where it should be. It only happens in the launcher. I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/883064/34648) to no avail.

Comment: Can you post your `lsb_release -rd` please?

Comment: I'm on 16.04.3.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

first do:

> modprobe -r psmouse
>
> modprobe psmouse

If it will not help, boot into grub (by holding shift) and perform RAM check.

another possible solution would be reinstalling drivers:

> sudo apt-get --reinstall install xserver-xorg-input-mouse

Comment: Does not help unfortunately.

Comment: did you do a reboot?

Comment: Yes. The cursor still gets stuck in the launcher.

Comment: edited the answer, please try new solution

Comment: I'm getting errors: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/25540554/

Comment: Those errors would probably be fixed by the last command. Seems like the mouse driver is somehow messed up.

Comment: With the last one I'm getting an error stating that the package "xserver-xorg-input-mouse" cannot be found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65655/discussion-between-chazecka-and-h3r3t1k).

Answer (score 0):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> when you arrive at the login screen.
2. Run `sudo service lightdm stop` to stop the X server.
3. Install NVidia-370:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-370 nvidia-settings
   ```
4. Add `blacklist nouveau` to bottom of file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.
5. Run `sudo update-initramfs -u`.
6. Run `sudo reboot` to restart.

Your mouse should have now appeared correctly! Please reply stating if this solution worked or not.

Comment: Why install nvidia drivers? I'm on intel graphics.

Comment: Try looking at this page, seemed to have a similar problem https://askubuntu.com/questions/838692/ubuntu-16-10-mouse-cursor-stays-in-upper-left-corner